# In Java, can a single Catch Block be shared by multiple Try Blocks?

Tags: java, try-catch

I am working on a java program that will be constructed by multiple methods, each with it's own try/catch blocks.  I find myself duplicating the same catch block in each try block.

Is there any way to have multiple try blocks use a single catch block?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

put the shared logic in a common method and invoke it from each catch block.

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
        try (BufferedReader autoClosable1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("")))) {
        }
        try (BufferedReader autoClosable2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("")))) {
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

//try it in java 7 onwards..

Comment: I wouldn't need a resource in my try block, so this will make the code less readable and less understandable. Besides you need to catch and handle `IOException`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can have multiple `try` declarations going off of one `catch`, but depending on the situation, you probably don't need it.

If the code you're writing throws the *same* exception, then it can all be handled in one `try...catch` statement.  Place all dodgy code within the `try` block and handle the exception that comes through.

If the code you're writing throws *different* exceptions, then with Java 7, you can [catch multiple exceptions within one `catch` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).  You'd still place the dodgy code in the one `try` block.

Comment: You can catch multiple with earlier than 7, 7 just introduced the multi-catch using bitwise or: `Exception | Exception`

Comment: Note the qualifier "within one catch block".  Yes, you can repeat the `catch` statements, but with 7, you can use *one*.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not do that. You have to have at least one catch block or a finally block in order the try block to be compiled. Since the finally block is anyway going to be executed no matter exception occurred or not you have to have catch block in case to handle the exception occurred. As the jtah says you can have a common method to be executed in each catch block.